# Debug mode restarts on the phone randomly

Tags: android, debugging, device

I have a strange issue with android development. I tried to debug my program with real device (samsung gt5660). I downloaded drivers from the official site - Samsung Kies. Then I switched phone into debug mode. After that usb connection was restarted every few seconds, so phone shows notifications "connection... debug mode on" again and again. I tried different usb port, then shut down Win7 and start Ubuntu 11.04 - and have the same result there. It's strange because on the other PC this phone works fine and doesn't restart debug mode every second.
Can anybody give an advice - what can I do to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't neet samsung kies to get ADB working. I experience a similar problem on my phone and I figured out it was simply a bad connector that would wiggle lose every few minutes.

Comment: I think, your are right. Another samsung phone with another data-cable works fine.